The event.over in handleDragEnd function return null (dnd drag and drop)
I have tried to implement the drag and drop function in my web page. But I encountered a difficulty, I am able to make my component draggable, but that draggable item cannot be drop in my droppable areas. I am using dnd-kit.
Sorry for the big chunk of code.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Typography} from "@mui/material";
import { DndContext, closestCorners } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import { useDroppable } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import PendingProjects from "../components/teaching/pendingProjects";
import Droppable from "../components/teaching/droppable"
import '../css/teachingTeam.css'

function TeachingTeam(){
    const {isOver,setNodeRef: setArrpovedDroppable} = useDroppable({id:"approved"})
    const {setNodeRef: setPendingDroppable} = useDroppable({id:"pending"})
    const {setNodeRef: setRejectDroppable} = useDroppable({id:"reject"})

    const style = {
        color: isOver ? 'green' : undefined,
    };

    function handleDragEnd(event){
        const {over, active } = event
        console.log(over, active)
        console.log(event)
        if (over) {
            switch (over.id) {
            case "approved":
                // Handle drop in the "Approved" section
                setApprovedList((prevList) => [...prevList, active.data]);
                setPendingList((prevList) => prevList.filter((item) => item.id !== active.data.id));
                setRejectList((prevList) => prevList.filter((item) => item.id !== active.data.id));
                break;
            case "pending":
                // Handle drop in the "Pending" section
                setPendingList((prevList) => [...prevList, active.data]);
                setApprovedList((prevList) => prevList.filter((item) => item.id !== active.data.id));
                setRejectList((prevList) => prevList.filter((item) => item.id !== active.data.id));
                break;
            case "reject":
                // Handle drop in the "Reject" section
                setRejectList((prevList) => [...prevList, active.data]);
                setApprovedList((prevList) => prevList.filter((item) => item.id !== active.data.id));
                setPendingList((prevList) => prevList.filter((item) => item.id !== active.data.id));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    const [rejectList, setRejectList] = useState([])
    const [approvedList, setApprovedList] = useState([])
    const [pendingList, setPendingList] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            name:"project 1"
        },
        {
             id: 2,
            name:"project 2"
        },
        {
             id: 3,
            name:"project 3"
        },
        {
             id: 4,
            name:"project 4"
        }
])
    

    return(
        <Box
            sx={{
            maxWidth:"1400px",
            height:"89vh",
            bgcolor:"black",
            display:{xs:"block",md:"flex",lg:"flex"},
            alignItems:"center",
            justifyContent:"left",
            margin:"0 auto"}}
        >
            <DndContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd} >
                
            <Box id="state-section" sx={{height:"100%",width:"400px", bgcolor:"lightgreen"}}>
                <Box id="approved-section" sx={{textAlign:"left",height:"30%",bgcolor:"green"}} ref={setArrpovedDroppable} style={style} onDragEnter={()=>{alert("enter!")}}>
                    <Typography sx={{borderBottom:1}}>Approved</Typography>
                    <Box className="content" >
                        {approvedList.map((item) => (
                                <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
                            ))}
                    </Box>
                </Box>

                <Box id="pending-section" sx={{textAlign:"left",height:"30%",bgcolor:"yellow"}}>
                    <Typography sx={{borderBottom:1}}>Pending</Typography>
                    <Box className="content" ref={setPendingDroppable}>
                        <PendingProjects projectList ={pendingList}/>
                    </Box>

                </Box>

                <Box id="reject-section"sx={{textAlign:"left",height:"30%",bgcolor:"red"}}>
                    <Typography sx={{borderBottom:1}}>Reject</Typography>
                    <Box className="content" ref={setRejectDroppable}>
                        {rejectList.map((item) => (
                                <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
                            ))}
                    </Box>
                </Box>

            </Box>
            </DndContext>
            <Box id="form-section"></Box>

        </Box>
    )
}
export default TeachingTeam

import React from 'react'
import Project from './project'

function pendingProjects(props) {
    const list = props.projectList
    return (
    <div>
            
      {list.map(function(e,i){
            return(
                <Project key={e.id} name={e.name} id={e.id}/>
            )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
export default pendingProjects

import React from 'react'
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import { useDraggable } from '@dnd-kit/core'
import { CSS } from '@dnd-kit/utilities'

const project = ({id, name}) => {
    const {attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform} = useDraggable({id:id})

    const style={
        transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform)
    }
  return (
    <div ref={setNodeRef} {...attributes} {...listeners} style={style}>
      <Button variant="outlined">{name}</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default project

I have read through the dnd-kit documentations. I have set the nodeRef for different droppable area , but it always returning null value for me. I don't know what happen. I assume something wrong with declaration with useDroppable?
Thanks for the reading up to this and appreciate the helps!

I think I know where the problem is. It loos like i cannot have useDrappable and DndContext together? When I put all those setNodeRef into a droppable file and then import this component into the file that has DndContext. I can get the droppable ref id. Does anyone know why I cannot have those two things together?
